# Logcat: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000 Что вызывает?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> 8559-8559/? E/appnameexample: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags:
>   0x8000

Работаю над приложением, которое воспроизводит *.ogg через `MediaPleyer`, где-то спустя неделю заметил это сообщение в Logcat, думал, что `MediaPleyer` это и вызывает, но даже после того как, закомментировал весь код с ним, сообщение осталось.   Есть идеи, что приводит к этой ошибке? Тут у парня аналогичный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56916587/6944861

---

Дополнение: Тестирую на физическом устройстве API 28, ошибки нет. На виртуальном API 29 - есть.

Comment: Этой информации не достаточно чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, если конечно кто-то не столкнулся один в один с этой же проблемой и не разбил весь лоб в кровь пока нашел ответ...

Comment: Та же проблема на API 29 при получении данных из веб. Ответ пока не нашёл, но на API 28 проблем нет.

Comment: Та же проблема на API 29 на эмуляторе и реальном девайсе